# What exactly is localStorage in html?

Tags: javascript, html

I've seen people use it before but I don't get what it does and how you would use it.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Comment: Show us what you have attempted to understand about it, *but I don't get what it does* does not warrant this as a fit for StackOverflow. Voting to close.

Comment: Use resources like https://developer.mozilla.org or https://msdn.microsoft.com or something similar to find such unswers. This will cower all you need about browser APIs. Have you ever googling ?

Comment: It's like cookies, but better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty easy to use, you can save everything local in your browser to reuse it later.

```
localStorage.setItem("key", "value");
localStorage.getItem("key");
```

Comment: thank you! This is very helpful!!

Comment: oh, I edited the question, so can you edit your answer please?

Answer (score 2):

It's storage for arbitrary string data, client-side.

In the past, even if your web app was 100% client-side and didn't use server resources, you still needed cookies and session data storage on the server to keep track of things from page load to page load.  Now, this isn't a requirement.  If you want to store data for re-use on the next page load, put it in local storage and it will be there the next time.

What you do with it is up to you and the needs of your application.

Comment: oh, I edited the question, so can you edit your answer please?

Comment: @Cursor You shouldn't just edit a question, totally changing that question.  Post a new question.